# Create a daily Sunday report in mysql

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks

How to create a daily Sunday report in mysql ? (each Sunday)

i want my report to be saved in a network disk . Is it possible ?

for example :

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY ONE WEEK 
    DO
SELECT titlea,titleb 
FROM tableX
INTO OUTFILE '\\network\Documents\Reports\test.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

nearly...,

You must specify the start date

```
CREATE EVENT `myevent ` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 7 DAY STARTS '2015-10-11 02:00:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO
BEGIN

SELECT titlea,titleb 
FROM tableX
INTO OUTFILE '\\network\Documents\Reports\test.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

END
```